# Unable to uninstall Miktex 2.9 on Windows 7

Tags: pdftex, miktex, windows

I am trying to uninstall MikTex 2.9 on Windows 7, but it won't uninstall. The wizard stops working. What can be done to solve this issue? One of the reasons I want to uninstall is that I am getting pdflatex.exe not working. This is the basic Miktex set up. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a hack (**use at your own risk!**): You can manually erase all and then use a registry cleaner to fix the entries. In the installed programs menu it should disappear by then or, if not, when you try to uninstall it, the system will detect it's not there and let you remove the entry.

Comment: If you still want to use MikTeX then remove the existing MikTeX installation  directory followed by reinstalling it. In my experience, there is no problem for doing this. But if you want to taste TeXLive then leave the MikTeX installation as if and install TeXLive. But you need to change `PATH` from pointing to MikTeX to pointing to TeXLive.

Comment: This looks rather more about Windows and the general 'how to uninstall an awkward program' issue than about TeX.